# How to access an ArcGIS Server secure service from java

Tags: arcgis-server, java, authentication, arcgis-web-adaptor

I want to call an ArcGIS Server service through Java. The service is locked and only the publisher and administrator can access it. 
If I know the credentials, what sort of authentication should I use? (I have web adaptor installed)

Comment: What types of authentication have you enabled?  Basic HTTP authentication requires HTTPS; Digest authentication requires configuration.  There are multiple potential paths, as well.  What have you tried?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure which of the provided methods to use. I have seen that such requests are handled using the proxy suggested by esri. However I would like to call the service from the backed (Java) using the apache httpclient. As a result I would like to keep is as simple as possible. I want just to pass the credentials in my post request and let it automatically login and perform the request.

Comment: This is on the cusp of not being a GIS question.  Without details, no answer is possible.

Comment: I tried basic http auth but it did not work. Maybe because i didnt use https.  If i want digest what sort of configuration should i do. ?

Comment: Basic authentication without encryption is inherently insecure (the password isn't transmitted in the clear, but it's decipherable without any effort, so it might as well be).  I have no idea what configuration is necessary for Digest authentication, but that's really a different question.  Most encryption is handled by plug-ins because of the weapons licensing requirements for shipping the capability within the product.